# How do I get HuggingFace analytics/metrics of uses?

Tags: huggingface, gradio

I want to know how many users I get on my application, and some interesting time series of uses. I see Gradio has `analytics_enabled` but I can't find any more information on it. (https://gradio.app/docs/)